# Generating all possible palindromes for a given string

Tags: c++, string, algorithm, palindrome

```
Inputs : I.1) A string of characters
Outputs: O.1) Total number of palindromes found
         O.2) Palindromes output on standard output

Note : duplicate palindromes are not allowed
             output need not be sorted
single characters are a palindrome.
```

I  have solved the above problem through backtracking but it is giving TLE for a big input string. So it will be beneficial if the solution avoids recursion.
Input for TLE is :- `amitabhbacchan`
 
Here's my implementation:

```
#include <iostream>
#include<bits/stdc++.h>
using namespace std;

int isSafe(int *a, int i) {
    if (a[i] == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

int isPalin(string b) {
    if (b.length() == 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    if (b.length() == 1) {
        return 1;
    }
    string c = b;
    std::reverse(c.begin(), c.end());
    if (c == b) {
        return 1;
    }
    else {
        return 0;
    }
}

void palindrome(string a, string b, int *vec, std::set<string>&res) {

    if (isPalin(b)) {
        if (res.find(b) != res.end()) {
            return;
        }
        res.insert(b);
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        if (isSafe(vec, i)) {
            b.push_back(a[i]);
            vec[i] = 1;

            palindrome(a, b, vec, res);
            b.pop_back();
            vec[i] = 0;
        }
    }
}

int main(void) {
    string a = "ababcdef";
    string c = "";
    int *vec;
    std::set<string>res;
    vec = (int*)malloc(a.length()*sizeof(int));
    for (int i = 0; i < a.length(); i++) {
        vec[i] = 0;
    }
    palindrome(a, c, vec, res);
    std::set<string>::iterator it;

    for (it = res.begin(); it != res.end(); it++) {
        cout << *it << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` Don't do that, this is not part of C++.

Comment: A brief explanation of why the first three lines of your program could cost you a job: `#include<bits/stdc++.h>` means include the entire standard library. `using namespace std;` means place the entire standard library in the global namespace. The standard library is huge, so this opens up a lot of room for silent overloads and other artifacts from naming collisions. The fubar potential is epic. Do this while interviewing for a job and you've just shouted at the top of your lungs  "I don't know how what I'm doing actually works."

Comment: And where is the question?

Answer (score 1):

The basic problem here is that you're generating palindromes very inefficiently. In particular, you're trying to generate every possible arrangement of the inputs, then checking whether each is a palindrome.

Instead of that, consider the basic requirements for a string to be a palindrome (all the characters before the middle are identical to, and in reverse order from, those after the middle). So, other than the middle character of an odd-length palindrome, every other character in the palindrome must occur an even number of times.

I'd start by separating the characters into two groups: even occurrences and odd occurrences. The characters that occur an even number of times you insert only half of those in the working set. That is, given (for example) `aabbccde` in your input, you'd break it into two pieces, one containing `abc` and the other containing `de`.

Then you can generate your palindromes by generating all the permutations of `abc` (and `ab`, `ac` and `bc`), which you output in forward order followed by the same set in reverse order (e.g., `abc` followed by `cba` giving `abccba`). Then for each of those, you can insert one character from the other set in the middle, so you get `abcdcba`, and `abcecba`). Then rearrange those inputs to get (for example) `acb` and repeat the process to get `acbbca`, `acbdbca` and `acbebca`.

One way to generate all the permutations of the "even" inputs is with `std::next_permutation`.

Note that this way you don't spend time generating lots of possible arrangements that aren't palindromes. You know up-front that every result you generate *will* be a palindrome.